# How to monitor the Utilization percentage of RDS metrics in aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

To place better alarms, I want to monitor the Utilization percentage of RDS metrics such as Free Memory, Free Storage, or Swap Usage rather than just the value in bytes.
Any help , how to do the same for RDS instances in aws account ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CloudWatch to do this with CloudWatch Alarms.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Monitoring.html

Enhanced monitoring provides you the proper metrics to calculate percentages -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.html

Additionally, I typically use DataDog for in-depth RDS monitoring.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/awsrds/

Comment: Thanks, but the provided links do not provide the required information.We are interested in fetching how much "percentage" of say,swap space has been utilized ? The cloudwatch returns the same in bytes.  We also tried using the percentage formula (used/total)*100. But, total metrics are also not available.

Comment: I've edited my answer to also include DataDog which gives you much more detail and would allow you to calculate the metrics you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks.. But question remains open and we are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Added detail about enhanced monitoring via Cloud Watch which provides you what you're asking for.